# How to extract numbers from string containing a dash

Tags: php

I have a string that contains this type of format 16/32/25

How can I extract these into 3 different strings like this

$i=16, $b=32, $c=25

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: The title says the string contains a dash. That string contains slashes, not dashes.

Comment: why the vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of [`list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list) and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```php
$string = '16/32/25';
list($a, $b, $c) = explode('/', $string);

echo $a; // 16
echo $b; // 32
echo $c; // 25
```